# XML parse error on installing Android SDK 1.6 on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: xml, rhomobile, android-sdk-1.6

I'm getting the following error after going through the setup /android-sdk-linux/tools/android.

> XML verification failed for http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository.xml.
>   Error: cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'sdk:sdk-repository'.
>   Failed to fetch URL http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository.xml, reason: Unknown

I have checked in ~/.android/androidtool.cfg and sdkman.force.http=true is correctly set.

Just FYI, I'm working with RhoMobile which is not compatible with the newest SDK so I had to use the newest of the old version. I read that the XML was reconfigured somewhere back in 1.5, but if that is the case, 1.6 shouldn't have issues.

I also verified that the XML file does contain data by loading it in a browser.

That's all the trouble shooting I've done so far. I don't know how else to approach this. I'm stumped.

Half my kingdom for a useful answer!

Comment: did you try https://.... ? Depending on the pc and my location (work, home, etc.) I need the secure sometimes and the plain others

Comment: @DrakeClarris: Failed to fetch URL https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository.xml, reason: SSL error. You might want to force download through http in the settings.

Comment: ha that figures. Was worth a shot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never ended up being able to get SDK 1.6 to work, but I realized that the newest SDK does actually work, the directions on [Rhomobile's site](http://docs.rhomobile.com/rhodes/build#build-for-android) for Android SDK install are just out of date. If you use the /android-sdk-linux/tools/android tool in the new SDK, you won't be able to follow the directions given, but common sense can get you through the interface and then the issues above are no longer present.

Hope this helps someone else!